# Getting npm caching to work for a .net core angular project in azure devops

Tags: angular, npm, caching, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a client project that takes about 15 minutes to build an Angular 10/.Net Core project and I'm trying to get the caching task to work. I've tried several permutations of the [configuration below](https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/improving-angular-ci-build-time-using-azure-devops-cache-task-ec059a45dd5d) but when I add `eq(variables['CacheRestored'],False)` as a run condition to the `npm install` task, the angular build task fails complaining about missing packages.

[image]

The project is setup as

```
.sln
xx.Web
   - ClientApp
     - package.json
```

The caching tasks **seems** like it's working:

[image]

Update:

For reference we are using `"postinstall": "ngcc",` so maybe the cache is working and it's the post install causing the slow down.

I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Eonasdan/c061616cd589d5d1bf022b9b00873193) with a stripped version of the pipeline yaml, and a post cache error message the questions doesn't get super long.

I'd love to speed up Angular 10s slow build times, but I'm sure that's a totally different question.

Solution:
[@Walter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842588/237917) fixed one of the errors I was getting. Fixing the path, removing the quotes and pointing to the ClientApp folder, was what fixed it.

Our builds went from 15 minutes to 7 minutes!

I've updated [my gist with a working yaml](https://gist.github.com/Eonasdan/c061616cd589d5d1bf022b9b00873193#file-working-pipe-yml) in case that helps someone in the future.

Comment: Just as an aside, try `npm ci` instead of `npm install` -- it's faster.

Comment: The MS docs suggest that ["Because npm ci deletes the node_modules folder to ensure that a consistent, repeatable set of modules is used, you should avoid caching node_modules when calling npm ci."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm)

Comment: Exactly, I'm suggesting using `npm ci` *instead* of caching, assuming the performance characteristics of `npm ci` meet your needs.

Comment: ah. I see. I'll give that a shot, see what happens and report back.

Comment: I followed your steps but it worked as expected on my side.
Can you provide the diagnostic logs of the first run and the second run for further troubleshooting?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT please see my update and the included gist. I created a test pipeline to try this out on.

Comment: also `npm ci` did not improve run time.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I did get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your Pipe.yaml:

`path: '"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/xx.Web/ClientApp/node_modules"'`

You need to remove the double quotes. The correct format should be:

`path:'$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/xx.Web/ClientApp/node_modules'`.

According to your post cache task log:

`tar: /home/vsts/work/1/s/â€œ/home/vsts/work/1/s/xx.Web/ClientApp/node_modulesâ€: Cannot open: No such file or directory`

You can also see that your path of the folder to cache is incorrect. Please change your path in your cache task to

`path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/xx.Web/ClientApp/node_modules'`.

Comment: why wouldn't the node_modules folder be where the package.json file is? I will try your suggestion. I'm just curious.

Comment: @Eonasdan You are right. I mean you need to change the format of the path. I updated my answer. The correct path for you should be: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/xx.Web/ClientApp/node_modules'.

Comment: I tidied up your answer a bit. The combination of the quotes and point to the ClientApp folder was what finally solved it. I didn't even noticed I had copied the quotes. Thanks for your help!